# How to send different commands to two different cmd windows in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have tried using subprocess module and win32 but it did not complete my requirement because SendKeys only works when we do not perform any activity while the script is in execution

I need to get adb devices connected to PC and then pass "adb reboot bootloader" command to each device by launching command prompts for each device

Can I get help in this?

```
import time
import re
import win32com.client
'''import win32api
from win32gui import GetWindowText
import win32clipboard
import win32con
from win32gui import GetForegroundWindow
from win32gui import SetForegroundWindow
from win32gui import EnumWindows'''
from win32process import GetWindowThreadProcessId


class ActivateVenv:

    ''' def set_cmd_to_foreground(self, hwnd, extra):
        """sets first command prompt to forgeround"""

        if "cmd.exe" in GetWindowText(hwnd):
            SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
            return'''

    def get_pid(self):
        """gets process id of command prompt on foreground"""

        #window = GetForegroundWindow()
        #return GetWindowThreadProcessId(window)[0]
        return GetWindowThreadProcessId()

    def activate_venv(self, shell, venv_location):
        """activates venv of the active command prompt"""

        print shell.AppActivate(self.get_pid())

    def run_py_script(self, shell,command):
        """runs the py script"""
        shell.SendKeys(command)

    def open_cmd(self, shell):
        """ opens cmd """

        shell.run("cmd.exe")
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    run_venv = ActivateVenv()
    command1 = "adb devices>output.txt {ENTER}"
    command3 = "exit {ENTER}"
    #command2 = "fastboot devices {ENTER}"
    #for i in{0,2}:
    run_venv.open_cmd(shell)
    #EnumWindows(run_venv.set_cmd_to_foreground, None)

    run_venv.run_py_script(shell,command1)
    run_venv.run_py_script(shell, command3)
    #run_venv.run_py_script(shell,command2)
    devices_list=[]
    f = open('output.txt', 'r')
    x = f.readlines()
    for i in x:
        r1 = re.findall(r"^\w+",i)
        if r1:
            devices_list.append(r1)
    f.close()
    print devices_list[2]
    #new_device = str(devices_list[2])
    #print(new_device.strip("',[,',]"))

    command2 = "adb -s "+ str(devices_list[2]).strip("',[,',]") + " reboot bootloader {ENTER}"
    run_venv.open_cmd(shell)
    #run_venv.run_py_script(shell, command2)
```

Comment: why you need to open command prompt windows?

Comment: I need to use a loop of continuous commands parallely for connected android devices which requires multiple command prompt windows

Answer (score 0):

Use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p1 = Popen(['cat'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(['cat'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdin.write(b'hello1\n')
p1.stdin.flush()
print('p1:%s' % p1.stdout.readline())
p2.stdin.write(b'hello2\n')
p2.stdin.flush()
print('p2:%s' % p2.stdout.readline())
p1.stdin.write(b'world1\n')
p1.stdin.flush()
print('p1:%s' % p1.stdout.readline())
p2.stdin.write(b'world2\n')
p2.stdin.flush()
print('p2:%s' % p2.stdout.readline())
```

This outputs:

```
p1:hello1
p2:hello2
p1:world1
p2:world2
```

Comment: Hi @blhsing thanx for the reply, but I need to launch two command prompt windows and send sequential commands to each window but in your code it executes in python console only

Comment: @shaikmustafa Show us your current code then. It's hard to see what you really mean by launching command prompt windows.